# Ruby on Rails: How to get the model/table modification time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

I know every row has its timestamp (modified_at), but I would like to get the time of the latest modification (row added/modified/deleted) of the database table.

I have a daemon running in the background that needs to periodically check if a table has changed.

So far, I haven't found a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`maximum` class method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#maximum) on your model:

```
whole_table_updated_at = YourModel.maximum('updated_at')
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just use the ActiveRecord-provided `maximum` method, like so

```
MyModel.maximum(:updated_on)
```